# Java - "super" , "this" or neither - good practice

Tags: java

As far as I understand, `this` can be used inside a class to call a method available in any of its superclass as the compiler will look for the method in its superclasses **if it's not available in the (sub)class**. Basically just like using a `super`.

So I was wondering, which is the better way of doing things? Is there a general rule of thumb for sing either?

**QUESTION**:

**When the method in question is not coded i.e only available via inheritance from its super class) in the (sub)class**, they basically do the same thing right? In *that* case, is there a reason to pick one over the other?

```
super.methodAvailableInSuper();
```

or

```
this.methodAvailableInSuper();
```

**MORE CLARIFICATION**

**WHY USE `this.` AT ALL?**

There seem to be two groups of people in this context : people who hate using `this` and people who love it. I am obviously no expert and these are only the arguments THEY (the people who recommend using it) use :

When you complete the message with `this.` you know for sure that you intended to send it to `this.`. Not using `this.` could mean you *might* have forgotten to write what you wanted to send the message to. It is used with variables to disambiguate the local variables from instance vairables

**`this`, `super` OR NEITHER? **

If you don't like using `this`, "neither" is your obvious answer because the compiler is not going to ask you for it.

If you think there is some point in using `this`, as a convention,  in the question's context, each has its benefits:

`super` makes sure overriding in the subclass doesn't affect the message send but if you prefer the code reflected the any changes made via override, you'd want `this`.

I was hoping there was a default/better choice already made by programmers after going through this thought process and that's what I am asking for.

Comment: Use super. inside methodAvailableInSuper if you need to call the method of methodAvailableInSuper superclass. If you do this.methodAvailableInSuper you will end with a recursion. Same is out method: use super. to call not overrided method.

Comment: there's usually no reason to use either. use super only if you don't want the method that is defined in the class and do want the method that is defined in a super class.

Comment: Why would you write `this.` at all inside the class?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Re your edit, see my edit.

Comment: If the method's not available in the subclass, there's no point in writing *either* `this.` *or* `super.` - best practice would be to write neither.

Comment: @DavidWallace I guess the problem is the way I am putting it.. My first question in SO and it definitely shows.. When i mean its not available, I mean its not coded in it but obviously "available" (i guess) due to inheritence from its parent class that has the method coded in it

Comment: Yes, I knew what you meant.  There is no point in writing `this.` or `super.` at all, in the case you describe.

Comment: @DavidWallace I think that's pretty much the closest answer I can get to.

Answer (score 6):

They're not equivalent, so your question isn't meaningful.

- this.method() will invoke the most-derived override of method(), including in any derived classes that this object may be an instance of
- super.method() will invoke the base class's implementation of method(), or whatever implementation it inherited if it doesn't provide an implementation itself.

You should use whichever one does exactly what you want. It's not just an aesthetic choice, or a question of 'good practice'.

**EDIT** Re your edited edit:

> When the method in question is not available in base class, they basically do the same thing right?

Wrong. `super` always calls a method in the base class or one of its parents. `this` calls the most-derived override. You would write `super` if you definitely didn't want to call any future implementation in any future derived class, and you would write `this`, or nothing, if you did want to call such an implementation if it exists when the call is made. Which is not something you can know when coding.

Comment: I have a nasty feeling that the OP didn't actually mean "base class" in the edit.

Comment: @DavidWallace I don't really care. I'm addressing what he wrote. I'm not interested in guesswork about whether he meant it, what he might have meant instead, ...

Comment: @EJP hmm my bad. I assumed "base class" means the "class in question" :$. So erm, can you please re-read the question replacing them appropriately :)

Comment: @rush001 `this` and `super` still mean two different things. I suggest for clarity that *you* do the replacing, *in your question,* so we can all agree what you're actually talking about.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a question of "best practice" since these keywords are very different.

When you call `super.methodAvailableInSuper();` then all parent classes are searched for this method at runtime. If this method exists in the current class or any subclass, this method wont be executed.

You can use this, if you want to call the super implementation of an overriden method without cousing an endless loop.

The keyword this calls the method on the current object. Thus the normal execution of methods will be performed.

See also:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Answer (score 0):

**WHY USE `this.` AT ALL?**

There seem to be two groups of people in this context : people who hate using `this` and people who love it. I am obviously no expert and these are only the arguments THEY (the people who recommend using it) use :

When you complete the message with `this.` you know for sure that you intended to send it to `this.`. Not using `this.` could mean you *might* have forgotten to write what you wanted to send the message to. It is used with variables to disambiguate the local variables from instance vairables

**`this`, `super` OR NEITHER? **

If you don't like using `this`, "neither" is your obvious answer because the compiler is not going to ask you for it.

If you think there is some point in using `this`, as a convention,  in the question's context, each has its benefits:

`super` makes sure overriding in the subclass doesn't affect the message send but if you prefer the code reflected the any changes made via override, you'd want `this`.

I was hoping there was a default/better choice already made by programmers after going through this thought process and that's what I am asking for.